# "no object or images found to bake to" error

Tags: objects, uv-image-editor

[image]

When i try to bake my model it come up with the error message 
"no object or images found to bake to"

Comment: Also make sure that the object is not restricted from rendering. This isn't a problem for OP but someone else might run into this issue.

Comment: To me it happened because I still hadn't applied the Mirror modifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create an image first. To do so click *new* in the UV Image Editor. Create your image and with it selected click *bake*. This only works in Blender Render like that. If you want to bake in Cycles you'll have to create an Image Texture Node in your material, don't connect it to anything, select your image and bake with the node selected. [image: Bake in Blender Render]

Comment: If you are in Blender Render you will also have to go into edit mode and select all, then select/add your image.

Comment: @pycoder it works in edit mode as well, you just have to have the object you want to bake selected. http://i.stack.imgur.com/6DbG0.gif

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well. Took me a while to realize that I have the mesh unselectable by disabling the mouse pointer. After I toggle it back on as below. It is able to bake now.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one: make sure the "**Use scene's active layers and camera**" little button, just near the layers grid on Object Mode, is on:

[image: hit dat button!]

All kind of weird things were happening to me (including baking problems) until I found out.

Comment: That was my problem, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

The camera (render) button in the Outliner next to eye (visibility) button also has to be on for both of the meshes. If it's unchecked for the object baked to (if baked is done from selection to active) there will be error as in the original post.

Comment: While this is not the case in the original post, unrenderability of the object can be a reason for the error

Comment: I can swear, I didn't click there! At least I know now that there is a hotkey to disable the render flag of an object  :-))

Answer (score 1):

click on the [image]

Blender has to know which object. Once you see the orange highlight means you are good to bake your image map

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Object mode, Tools, and change shading to flat

Edit:

Sorry I was wrong. First make sure that you have an image and it should be open in the UV editor then You just have to select "Selected To Active" then press bake.

Comment: Shading won't make object have an image avaible for baking to it

Answer (score 0):

Also, another thing can happen. Make sure "Bake to Vertex Color" just above "Clear" is checked off in the Baking panel.

This just happened to me. I must have selected it accidentally.