# my baked uv doesnt go on my model

Tags: uv, game-engine, texture-baking, baking

I have been slamming my head against my keyboard since last night trying to figure this out. I want to bake the fabric and the metal into one material to port but it just ends up like this. Please help[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj5UN.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for you but simply put you need a selected texture in the image editor and then make sure all layers you want baked are selected with the button next to the layers ( in object mode ) "Use scene's active camera and layer's in this view, rather than local layers" is active and dark grey ( light grey is off ).

["no object or images found to bake to" error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61473/no-object-or-images-found-to-bake-to-error)

Oh and i use blender render and use a single material with each texture assigned to the single material but you should be able to use multiple materials as long as the model is using those materials, with corresponding textures.

EDIT: Make sure you bake full render and account for lighting.

Comment: and by layers im assuming you mean materials?

Comment: wait nevermind i think i got it